# python: Why more documents are processed than the number of documents in collection

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, count, document

I am using a for-loop on a mongo collection and update each document. To check how many documents have been processed, I use enumerate and my codes are like:

```
for r, d_100 in enumerate(grid100.find().batch_size(1000)):
    self_grid = grid100.find({'_id':d_100['_id']})
    ......
    ......
    (processing)
    grid100.update({'_id':d_100['_id']},{'$set':{u'big_cell4':{"POI":venue_count, "cell_ids":cell_ids}}})

    if r % 1000 == 0:
        print ("%d records processed in %2.3f" % (r, time.time()-t0))
        t0 = time.time()
```

The problem is that, using grid100.count() in mongo shell, I know there are **64141** documents, but when I run my codes, in the end it shows "**79000 records processed in 89.857**". I think this means 79000 documents are processed. Am I right? If I am right, then why more documents are processed and where do they come from?

Comment: Have you tried investigating an "extra" document? You should be able to modify your code to find out a lot of information about anything "extra" that's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, what do you mean by "extra" document?